# Does installing ubuntu dual boot with Windows 8 preinstalled via liveusb overwrite Windows bootloader?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have used Ubuntu a lot, mostly through dual boot with windows. I had recently purchased new laptop with Windows 8, on which I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64 through wubi like before but I could not. I searched many questions here and came to conclusion that wubi just won't install on system with UEFI, because it is not campatible with GPT. So I had to look for other ways. Mainly I want to keep my UEFI/safe mode setting so that I am able to boot Windows 8.

I tried to follow this post : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI to install Ubuntu. I have two problems :

1. Not an issue faced yet, but it says in the guide to run Boot-Repair. Why is it required and does it modify the main Windows bootloader.
2. The problem happens when I boot via liveusb just (to test the possibility). I reach a screen which is similar to one under `If the BIOS is set up to boot the CD in EFI mode`. But there are three such menus with teeny tiny fonts squeezed in the same screen space. Same menu but three times, moving cursor shows changes in all of them.

I am not sure what to do here. Is it a known bug ? What should I do to install Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 8. Has anyone successfully installed ubuntu this way. Please Help.

Comment: Visitors see question http://askubuntu.com/questions/481049/ubuntu-14-04-liveusb-boot-screen-graphic-errors/482977#482977 for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Repair doesn't technically modify the Windows boot loader, but it does rename it. IMHO, renaming the Windows boot loader by default, as Boot Repair does, is unjustified, because this can cause problems down the road. There is an option in Boot Repair to *not* make this change. The recommendation to use Boot Repair is common because there are a number of common problems with EFI-mode installation, caused both by buggy EFIs and by problems in the Ubuntu installer; however, IMHO, Boot Repair should be used only as a last resort. See [my page on this utility](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html) for more of my thoughts on the issue.

I'm not sure what you mean by your problem #2. Perhaps a screen shot (taken with a digital camera) would help clarify the problem.