# Ubuntu 14.04 liveusb boot screen graphic errors

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Y500 laptop. It came preinstalled with Windows 8. I want to install it in a separate partition with a USB drive. I have tried both Unetbootin and universal usb installer. But for some reason the screen after booting is crappy.

The screen goes blank after selecting try ubuntu or install. If I try with `nomodeset` option the screen only displays on a small strip on the top. Which again is split into three. Each seem to be identical. It is not decent enough to begin installation.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

The graphic card in my laptop is Nvidia GT650M, if it helps. Maybe the problem is related to that. Can anyone help in fixing this error when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu?  While reinstalling you should also download the updates during installation which may fix the graphics problem. Can you also try using a different monitor if you have one?  Thanks

Comment: @Adam That happens when installing via liveusb. I already mentioned I cannot continue the installation. I don't have a monitor getting one could take a while. Can you suggest anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I diagnosed the problem to be bootloader not being able to recognize the graphics mode for the laptop. And that it is forcing an unsupported one by default which should not happen. And ends up  drawing smaller screen.

I managed to work around the situation by adding/modifying a line in my bootable liveusb drive's /boot/grub.cfg :

```
set gfxmode=1024x768
```

This along with the `nomodeset` option allows me to boot with correct graphic settings. I can see the splash and try ubuntu with full(er) resolution now.

If you have similar issue, try setting the gfxmode yourself. And after installing ubuntu you would need proprietary graphic drivers and also `nomodeset` option to boot properly.